# how to fix TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session_name'?

Tags: python

I tried to deploy [this bot](https://github.com/odysseusmax/utube) to heroku but i got this error

```
File "/app/bot/utubebot.py", line 8, in __init__
super().__init__(
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session_name'
```

utubebot.py code

```
from pyrogram import Client

from .config import Config


class UtubeBot(Client):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
        session_name=Config.SESSION_NAME,
        bot_token=Config.BOT_TOKEN,
        api_id=Config.API_ID,
        api_hash=Config.API_HASH,
        plugins=dict(root="bot.plugins"),
        workers=6,
    )
    self.DOWNLOAD_WORKERS = 6
    self.counter = 0
    self.download_controller = {}
```

to be sincere , I'm a noob in python , i need detailed help plz :)

Comment: Simply put, the `Client` class does not have a `session_name` argument. Perhaps refer to the documentation to be sure you’re creating the instance correctly; (i.e. passing in the correct parameters).

Comment: The error says what the problem is - pyrogram Client does not expect an argument named `session_name` that you are currently passing it. Expected arguments can be found here: https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/client#pyrogram.Client

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Silvio's answer, but he's got half of the answer. The author of the bot you're linking did in fact mean `session_name`, but you'll note that the latest version of the application was released on Jun 27, 2021. At that time, the latest version of library it's calling *pyrogram* was on a 1.xx build and took a `session_name` parameter in the `Client` class. As of version 2.0.0, it no longer does. The solution is to downgrade the dependency version of *pyrogram* to one that matches the API `utube` is developed against, or to upgrade `utube` to meet the new API.

This kind of thing is why it's important to specify a dependency's version in the *requirements.txt* file -- had the author anchored the version, saying something like `pyrogram==1.2.0`, the error wouldn't come up. When you don't specify a version (like just `pyrogram`, as the author has done), the latest version gets installed, even if there are breaking changes.

Link to the `Client` implementation in v1.2.0 of *pyrogram*, which is the latest version before the latest release of `utube`: https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/blob/v1.2.0/pyrogram/client.py. Notice that the constructor does include *session_name*, and is otherwise structured pretty differently from the latest release, linked here: https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/blob/master/pyrogram/client.py. It seems like `session_name` was in fact renamed to `session_string`, but the semantics of how it's handled and validated are a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Client` constructor](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/client) does not take a `session_name` argument. You can see a full list of the accepted arguments at that link. Perhaps you meant `name` or `session_string`. It's difficult to tell from the code you've shown, so I recommend reading that page and seeing which argument you meant to pass.